# Create MySQL Table in JSP

Tags: mysql, jsp

Is there a way to create a MySQL table in JSP dynamically? Ideally it would be for use in a forum the user types the name of a thread and it would create a table with that name in the database.

I'm thinking small for the time being though I can't see if it's actually do-able i've given it a go but it didn't work, in fairness I didn't expect it to.

This is what I've tried,

```
<sql:query var="dbData1">
    CREATE TABLE test (id int NOT NULL)
</sql:query>
```

Comment: You will get alot of tables if you have alot of users. Why not a standard relational database setup with User_Id etc?

Comment: This was the only way that I'd thought of as of yet it would only be used by 20 people max as an intranet forum, I can't see it being used that much I am open to suggestions though

Answer (score 2):

You need a `dataSource` defined and the same is referred in the `query` statement.

***Example 1***:

Define DataSource like this:

```
<sql:setDataSource var="dsn" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_database_name_here"
     user="userName"  password="pass_code_here"/>
```

And, refer the same DSN in the query constructor like this:

```
<sql:query dataSource="${dsn}" var="dbData1">
    CREATE TABLE test (id int NOT NULL);
</sql:query>
```

This kind of `dsn` definition in `jsp` is not advised to be practised.
In the above example you can see that the Database access credentials are exposed open.
You better define the DSN in your server config file (for example server.xml for Tomcat) and use it.

***Example 2***:

If you are using Tomcat, then define the [data source in Server.xml](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Configuring+a+MySQL+Datasource+in+Apache+Tomcat#ConfiguringaMySQLDatasourceinApacheTomcat-Step3.ConfigureTomcat), like this:

```
<Resource
    name="jdbc/dsn_on_my_db"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    username="yourusername"
    password="yourpassword"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db_name_here"
    maxActive="15"
    maxIdle="7"
    validationQuery="Select 1" />
```

And in your jsp page refer to the DSN like this:

```
<sql:setDataSource dataSource="jdbc/dsn_on_my_db" />
```

And, use the query as you defined in your posting:

```
<sql:query var="dbData1">
    CREATE TABLE test (id int NOT NULL);
</sql:query>
```

Alternatively,

```
<sql:query var="dbData1"
     dataSource="${applicationScope.dsn_on_my_db}">
```

Comment: Cheers for your answer the datasource is already provided it connects to the database already, I made it inside an existing jsp application to test the logic